# What is the difference between multiplying final and non final int variables?

Tags: java

Consider this code snippet

```
public class ConstantFolding {

   static final  int number1 = 5;
   static final  int number2 = 6;

   static int number3 = 5;
   static int number4 = 6;

   public static void main(String[ ] args) {
      int product1 = number1 * number2;             //line A
      int product2 = number3 * number4;             //line B
   }
}
```

What is the difference between the line marked as line A and the line marked as line B?

Comment: I would vote to reopen after perhaps editing the question a little, it turns out to be a valid question (which triggered a very good answer) perhaps in a coating of a post that could have been written a little more verbosely, am I completely wrong?

Comment: Also, it doesn't deserve 3 down votes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that the multiplication required for `product1` is performed at *compile-time* as `number1` and `number2` are constants.

The calculation for `product2` is compiled at execution time, as the values of `number3` and `number4` can change. Indeed, you could change the values and then call `main` again.

See sections [15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)  and [4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) of the JLS for more information about constant expressions and constant variables.

Comment: Interesting. Makes sense, but did not come to mind. Good answer.

Comment: @Jon - you managed to take a -4 question and make it the most interesting new thing I learned today about Java

Comment: @EranMedan: Excellent! Always glad to turn something around :)

Comment: and now, it's +1 and reopened. I love SO

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, `product1` and `product2` are both equal to 30.

The message hit you because you cannot just post a code statement without any explanation.

Comment: i was asking any programmatic difference or runtime or compile time difference, or some thing like that... i got it finally.. but how to look at byte code. ?